# Flutter How to create box container in price tag shape

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-design

How to create this corner-shaped card view in a flutter container..
[image: How to create this corner shaped card view in a flutter container..?]

Comment: please share some code

Comment: @JahidulIslam,
The below answer works for me.
Cheers!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can archive this in several ways, using

- [Container Decoration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html)
- [ClipPath](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html)
- [CustomPaint](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html)

Here is a demo of using CustomPaint, modify the value the way you like.

**Result**

[image]

**Painter**

```dart
class PriceTagPaint extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.green
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    Path path = Path();

    path
      ..moveTo(0, size.height * .5)
      ..lineTo(size.width * .13, 0)
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width * .13, size.height)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height * .5)
      ..close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    //* Circle
    canvas.drawCircle(
      Offset(size.width * .13, size.height * .5),
      size.height * .15,
      paint..color = Colors.white,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

**And use**

```
SizedBox(
      height: 100,
      width: 300,
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: PriceTagPaint(),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Coolant",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 44,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

**Check on** [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=ad326ddafd976bae1fd224bc4b3bef5b&null_safety=true) or on [gist](https://gist.github.com/yeasin50/ad326ddafd976bae1fd224bc4b3bef5b)

Comment: @ Yeasin_Sheikh, Cheers!
This made my day happy. I'm new in Flutter .. );

Comment: Sure...
@ Yeasin_Sheikh, Is it possible to apply corner radius & elevation in this view...?

Comment: We need to use brazier curve in that case a little complicated, for easy way try on [shapemaker](https://shapemaker.web.app/#/)